# Failed to deploy Spring boot application on Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, heroku-api

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application on Heroku and I am getting this error:

heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=a
pi-demo-java.herokuapp.com request_id=b129b503-cdb1-4441-8b7f-6fd475c477e6 fwd="82.77.127.119" dyno= connect= se
rvice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-31T10:33:09.244588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.
ico" host=api-demo-java.herokuapp.com request_id=a124f92d-e685-4e8b-b8d9-24a2ad5a59c0 fwd="82.77.127.119" dyno=
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I tried to set the port in application properties and I am not using favicon.ico anywhere.

This is my application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apidemo
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

    ## Hibernate Properties
    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen 
    database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

    server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please share some code and configuration

Comment: @BeppeC I have added my applications.properties file, what else do you need?